# Как создать переменную в .then, чтобы был доступ к ней позже

Tags: node.js, firebase, promise

В Firebase Cloud Firestone есть способ достать данные с помощью `get()`, вот этот код:

```
let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');
let getDoc = cityRef.get()
  .then(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
      console.log('No such document!');
    } else {
      console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting document', err);
  });
```

Но предположим, что мне нужно создать переменную с данными, взятыми из базы. Как правильно это сделать? Если я начну создавать переменную внутри `.then`, то в дальнейшем node.js не будет видеть эту переменную и будет считать ее не объявленной. А если я ее создам после `.then`, то node.js скажет, что она не объявлена. Как поступить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант обернуть все в async/await

```js
(async () => {
  
  let url = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8,%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a614dfef8cf0b3fbd5%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%222d3b5239-3bc9-46c9-8ca0-c5b4a5b1cd72%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%241%2C694.34%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2029%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Roth%20Chapman%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22male%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22BIOLIVE%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22rothchapman%40biolive.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(945)%20461-3128%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22889%20Navy%20Street%2C%20Williamson%2C%20Kentucky%2C%203805%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Lorem%20cupidatat%20velit%20non%20excepteur%20do.%20Proident%20in%20minim%20incididunt%20ipsum%20nisi.%20Nulla%20eu%20labore%20mollit%20incididunt%20deserunt%20dolor.%20Sunt%20aliqua%20in%20occaecat%20anim%20reprehenderit%20deserunt%20sunt%20et%20consectetur%20quis%20non%20velit%20ad.%20Elit%20elit%20pariatur%20nisi%20eiusmod%20anim.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222017-11-05T12%3A43%3A07%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%2016.213871%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%2056.361562%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22velit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22non%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aliqua%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ad%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aute%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22occaecat%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22non%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Mccullough%20Mcintosh%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Valentine%20Mcclure%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Emily%20Spears%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Roth%20Chapman!%20You%20have%208%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22banana%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a6a67794d937294e01%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%2272d204d7-21ac-4b1f-9090-e4ac2ce289ac%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%241%2C254.50%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2034%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22brown%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Vaughn%20Harris%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22male%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22ZAGGLES%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22vaughnharris%40zaggles.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(964)%20522-2918%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22746%20Kermit%20Place%2C%20Como%2C%20California%2C%206198%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Enim%20reprehenderit%20ea%20voluptate%20veniam.%20Irure%20et%20minim%20ea%20labore%20adipisicing%20commodo%20enim%20Lorem%20eu%20nulla%20dolor.%20Incididunt%20amet%20esse%20sit%20occaecat%20sit%20deserunt%20in%20fugiat%20tempor%20Lorem%20sint%20tempor.%20Nostrud%20qui%20ad%20dolore%20eu%20aliqua%20commodo%20eu%20laboris%20dolore.%20Laborum%20non%20sit%20proident%20et%20velit%20amet%20deserunt%20dolore%20qui%20est%20ea%20commodo%20dolor%20consequat.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222017-06-10T03%3A47%3A22%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-81.584673%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%20165.608442%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aute%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22esse%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22proident%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22in%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22quis%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22velit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Lorem%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Spears%20Nash%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Torres%20Merritt%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Shauna%20Trujillo%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Vaughn%20Harris!%20You%20have%206%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22strawberry%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a68f80e562bec7e6e3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%2204130d19-e194-458a-830f-c06de47f3e82%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%243%2C217.95%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2025%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Chapman%20Williams%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22male%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22CHORIZON%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22chapmanwilliams%40chorizon.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(857)%20565-3601%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22714%20Sands%20Street%2C%20Troy%2C%20Rhode%20Island%2C%209365%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Consectetur%20ad%20cillum%20elit%20nisi%20Lorem%20anim%20laborum%20magna%20velit%20ea%20ipsum%20eu%20laboris%20tempor.%20Ex%20minim%20veniam%20officia%20culpa%20tempor%20commodo%20occaecat%20irure%20anim%20sit%20sit%20amet.%20Eiusmod%20labore%20aute%20consectetur%20est%20qui%20qui%20ea%20aute%20elit%20ex%20consequat%20cupidatat.%20Cupidatat%20anim%20anim%20anim%20eu%20exercitation%20incididunt%20et%20aliquip%20ad%20aliqua%20laborum.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222018-07-31T07%3A46%3A47%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-85.02954%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%2045.919093%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aliqua%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22aute%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22enim%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22consequat%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22proident%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22commodo%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22anim%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Bernadine%20Freeman%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Carney%20Moses%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Reed%20Camacho%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Chapman%20Williams!%20You%20have%209%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22strawberry%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a6489821ad3d9a6dac%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%22abaa4487-6198-41bf-94d8-a42ac35ae2d6%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%243%2C713.77%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2037%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Benita%20Kane%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22female%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22JETSILK%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22benitakane%40jetsilk.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(825)%20476-3734%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22743%20High%20Street%2C%20Gibbsville%2C%20Michigan%2C%201086%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Nulla%20enim%20ex%20amet%20deserunt%20quis%20quis%20sit%20laboris%20ullamco%20magna%20esse%20dolor%20et.%20Sit%20fugiat%20incididunt%20enim%20pariatur%20consectetur%20ipsum.%20Qui%20elit%20mollit%20eiusmod%20mollit%20amet%20irure%20nulla.%20Pariatur%20Lorem%20nisi%20et%20ad%20aliquip%20irure%20ut%20culpa%20minim%20sunt%20sunt%20consectetur%20commodo%20deserunt.%20Ut%20aliquip%20consectetur%20esse%20duis%20sit.%20Aliquip%20elit%20ex%20deserunt%20id%20laboris%20elit%20fugiat%20nulla%20laboris%20elit%20proident%20velit%20irure.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222016-10-07T12%3A36%3A44%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%2062.654347%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%20-122.744685%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22pariatur%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ea%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22do%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mollit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sunt%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22amet%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22eiusmod%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Fern%20Bond%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Ellis%20Salinas%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Owens%20Kennedy%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Benita%20Kane!%20You%20have%206%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22banana%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a6a5af37cd382d9d9b%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%228309d5a6-32bb-44dd-b983-c1b27f818b55%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%241%2C638.40%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2028%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Francis%20Hyde%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22female%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22PARLEYNET%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22francishyde%40parleynet.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(864)%20427-2987%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22117%20Grand%20Avenue%2C%20Wolcott%2C%20New%20Jersey%2C%209212%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Voluptate%20ullamco%20consequat%20deserunt%20duis%20nostrud%20incididunt.%20Officia%20magna%20in%20irure%20ullamco%20fugiat%20dolore%20eu%20ex.%20Ex%20esse%20et%20pariatur%20et%20adipisicing%20dolor%20ut%20commodo%20magna%20sit%20dolor%20irure.%20Proident%20qui%20eiusmod%20enim%20aliquip%20laborum%20officia%20est%20pariatur%20commodo%20laboris%20ex.%20Anim%20officia%20labore%20aliquip%20id%20deserunt%20incididunt.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222014-09-09T04%3A03%3A23%20-06%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-64.952187%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%2036.369537%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sint%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Lorem%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ut%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22esse%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22voluptate%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ea%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22consectetur%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Amanda%20Lester%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Stella%20Huffman%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Weaver%20Kaufman%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Francis%20Hyde!%20You%20have%201%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22strawberry%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a6cf1fdbcc93ffbc8c%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%205%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%22822dd125-e2b9-428c-a98c-fdb3cc386f79%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%241%2C602.61%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2040%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22brown%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Pennington%20Sutton%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22male%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22BUZZMAKER%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22penningtonsutton%40buzzmaker.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(911)%20512-2131%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22765%20Stillwell%20Avenue%2C%20Westmoreland%2C%20Federated%20States%20Of%20Micronesia%2C%207938%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Dolor%20incididunt%20dolor%20in%20sit.%20Exercitation%20id%20fugiat%20ullamco%20ipsum%20dolore%20quis%20labore.%20Qui%20incididunt%20in%20ipsum%20minim%20aliqua%20ullamco%20Lorem%20id%20sint.%20Excepteur%20deserunt%20labore%20enim%20id%20sunt%20do%20laborum%20aliquip%20excepteur%20duis%20reprehenderit.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222017-05-17T10%3A31%3A22%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-54.521168%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%20125.303514%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Lorem%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ipsum%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22adipisicing%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22labore%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mollit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cupidatat%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22exercitation%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Richmond%20Nieves%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Madelyn%20Flowers%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Miller%20Carver%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Pennington%20Sutton!%20You%20have%202%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22banana%22%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22_id%22%3A%20%225d7887a6c623fc6ad56343ad%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22index%22%3A%206%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22guid%22%3A%20%228d4f7c3d-666c-4386-a1fa-ccf20d80f953%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22isActive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22balance%22%3A%20%22%243%2C041.76%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22picture%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fplacehold.it%2F32x32%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2030%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22eyeColor%22%3A%20%22blue%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Hewitt%20Mathis%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22male%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22company%22%3A%20%22KEEG%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22email%22%3A%20%22hewittmathis%40keeg.com%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22phone%22%3A%20%22%2B1%20(886)%20474-2537%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22address%22%3A%20%22444%20Cortelyou%20Road%2C%20Cawood%2C%20Mississippi%2C%203332%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22about%22%3A%20%22Irure%20do%20qui%20mollit%20fugiat%20commodo%20proident%20consequat%20cupidatat%20aute%20irure%20nostrud%20proident%20ad%20cupidatat.%20Ex%20elit%20do%20aliqua%20aliqua%20aliqua.%20Labore%20cupidatat%20officia%20amet%20cupidatat%20voluptate%20eiusmod.%20Dolor%20proident%20pariatur%20do%20exercitation.%20Ea%20nostrud%20laboris%20tempor%20deserunt%20dolore.%20Quis%20Lorem%20elit%20enim%20occaecat%20cillum%20dolore%20veniam.%5Cr%5Cn%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22registered%22%3A%20%222016-05-23T06%3A39%3A03%20-05%3A00%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22latitude%22%3A%20-10.553852%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22longitude%22%3A%20-30.656601%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22tags%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22pariatur%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22enim%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sunt%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22cupidatat%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22sit%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22duis%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22officia%22%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22friends%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Latonya%20May%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Eloise%20Boyle%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22Mosley%20Oneal%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22greeting%22%3A%20%22Hello%2C%20Hewitt%20Mathis!%20You%20have%205%20unread%20messages.%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22favoriteFruit%22%3A%20%22apple%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D";

  
  function get(){
    return fetch(url).then(data => {
       return data.json();
    })
  };
  
  let json = await get();
  
  console.log(json);
  
})();
```

Для того, чтобы в дальнейшем работать с данными полученные из вне, нужно из асинхронного кода сделать синхронный. Для этого используются Promise или async/await (это тоже Promise, только в более симпатичном виде).

ваш код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
(async () => {

  try{
    let cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

    let response = await cityRef.get();
    let doc =  response.json();
    console.log(doc);
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error getting document', error);
  }  
  
})();
```

Изучите работу Promise, а так же async/await. Вам оно еще не раз пригодится.

Comment: К сожалению я не понимаю как можно применить этот код, можете объяснить?

Comment: @ДаняСацук обновил ответ

Comment: У вас есть небольшая ошибка, вместо `response.json()` у вас должно быть `response.data()`, а так все верно